# VS Code Blank Screen on Opening

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, path, gpu, mingw-w64

When I try to open VS Code it shows a blank screen.
[VS Code on opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrfWt.png)

Then as suggested by some other answers I tried adding --disable-gpu to the target which is given as: "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"--disable-gpu

On clicking OK. I have the following error.
[Post the suggested solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLNt4.png)

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I may be able to help with the error. It indicates `Code.exe` is not found in the location you've specified, `C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe`. I find it installed to that location. Perhaps something is mistyped.

Comment: Notice you seem to have no space preceding `--disable-gpu` That is likely a mistake. Also notice the path includes spaces in a folder name, `Microsoft VS Code`. That necessitates surrounding the full path name in double quotes, e.g. `"C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"`. Your image makes it seem as though you've done that but then also surrounded everything in single quotes. I don't think you should do the later.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late for this answer, but unfortunately nothing worked above mentioned answers. So here is my answer:

I uninstalled the VS code completely from my machine following steps from this link: https://debug.to/1074/how-to-uninstall-vs-code-completely#:%7E:text=1%20Go%20to%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20path.%20%25LocalAppData%25%5CPrograms%5CMicrosoft,the%20.vscode%20folder%20at%20the%20below%20path%20%25UserProfile%25

I then disabled my anti-virus software. In my case, it was Quick Heal security (expired).

I installed the VS Code again on my machine, and IT WORKED!

I have been looking into this issue since 3 days! And finally, I am happy that it is working.

the file JS.NEMUCOD.AF prevents desktop from showing its contents
when antivirus quartines this files vscode doesnt work properly